# Does the mass of the iron core affect the strength of an Electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

When teaching electromagnetism in schools, many teachers make use of an apparatus similar to this:

[image: Electromagnet]

[Image source.](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/electromagnets.html)

This got me wondering, does the mass of the iron nail affect the strength of the magnet?

Comment: How would you change the mass of the iron, exactly?  Making it longer (more turns)?  Making it thicker (more area)?  Making it denser (different element that's not ferromagnetic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this scenario would be mass independent. The strength of a solenoid's field with no core is B=unI while the strength of a solenoid with a core is B=kunI with k being a constant which is the relative permeability of the core substance. As you can see, by just adding a constant with a core, it would be mass independent.

B = Magnetic field strength (Teslas)

u = Permeability of free space (1.26*10^-6 Tm/A... I actually don't remember the rest of this unit)

n = The number of turns over the length of the wire. You will also see this written as N/L.

I = The current flowing through the wire (Amperes)

k = The relative permeability of the core substance (dimensionless)